# ADF Pipeline include fixed text in output

Tags: azure-data-factory

The overall aim of the pipeline is to copy from XML to Oracle.

One of the source columns is a datetime that needs formatting, so I'm using an intermediate copy activity to copy from XML to CSV as instructed in [this answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/845723/adf-pipeline-format-datetime-from-xml-source.html)

From the CSV to the table is simple mapping except for the need for an additional target column with a fixed value of '365Response'

I've tried adding this as an additional column as shown below:

[image]

However, on the mapping tab, I'm not able to select the new additional column:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hi, your process looks correct, can you try clear and import schema again in mapping?

Comment: that worked - thank you. Would you like to add an answer and I'll mark as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process to add an `Additional column` in the copy activity looks correct. If the Additional column is not showing in the mapping, you can **clear** the mapping and **import schema** again to refresh the mapping.

[image]